# How to keep navbar height fixed even if it contains a bigger item (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a NavBar in Boottrap that holds couple of times. One of them is a box that its height is bigger than the whole bar. The problem is the navbar height increases while the item is bigger. I want to item fall out of the navbar if its bigger. and also keep the responsive aspect too.

DEMO:http://www.bootply.com/oeFRrvH8pl

My code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">NAME</a>
                
            </div>
            <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <div class="red">
                12345678 <br> Call us
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

This image is what I am looking to achieve: [image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Set a fixed height on the nav. Like so:

```
.navbar {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It can work, but in smaller screens, it will go completely out of nav bar, since nav bar cannot hold it and has a fixed height.

Comment: That's because of the classes you're using on the red thing. That's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `.navbar`'s height to `10px` (or however big you want to make it) using CSS.

Comment: It works but in small screens it goes out of the navbar.

Answer (score 1):

Except other answer to set a `height` for `.navbar`, you can also change the `position` of `.red` like below:

```
.red{
    position: absolute;
    padding:15px;
    background-color:red;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take that element out of your nav

```
<style>
.red{
position:relative;
margin-top:-"here specify the nav height";
right:0;
z-index:99
}

</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">NAME</a>

            </div>

        </div>
</nav>
                <div class="red">
                12345678 <br> Call us
                </div>
```